# How to Replace the String in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the string `string test="http://www.test.com//web?testid=12"`.

I need to replace with in the string **//** into **/**.

Problem is if I use `string a=test.replace("//","/")` I get **http:/www.test.com/web?testid=12** all with single slash(/) but I need **http://www.test.com/web?testid=12**.

I need only the second **//** nearby **web**, not first **//** near by **www**.

How to do this?

Comment: Where is the URL string coming from?  Is it a URL that you generate, or is it a string coming from an external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string test = @"http://www.test.com//web?testid=12";
test = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf(@"//") - 1) 
       + test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf(@"//")).Replace(@"//", @"/");
```

Or since its a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), you can do:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(test);
string newTest = uri.Scheme + @"//" + uri.Authority 
                                    + uri.PathAndQuery.Replace(@"//",@"/");
```

Comment: I think you'll need to add the port as well, in case it's not the default for the scheme.

Comment: @mleroy, yeah, but I would use [uri.Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx) in that case, rather than uri.Host,

Answer (score 3):

You can make second replace

```
string test="http://www.test.com//web?testid=12";
string a=test.Replace("//","/").Replace("http:/","http://");
```

=)

Answer (score 0):

```
string test="http://www.test.com//web?testid=12"
string[] test2 = test.Split('//');

string test = test2[0] + "//" + test2[1] + "/" + test2[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(test, "[^:]//", "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use stringbuilder as well.

StringBuilder b =new StringBuilder();

b.Replace("/","//",int startindex,int count);

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove one of the last slashes with `String.Remove()`:

```
string test="http://www.test.com//web?testid=12";
string output = test.Remove(test.LastIndexOf("//"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = "http://someurl//data";
var splitindex = http.IndexOf("/") + 1;
var res = http.Substring(splitindex+1, (http.Length-1) - splitindex).Replace("//","/");
http = "http://" + res;
```

Or

```
StringBuilder strBlder = new StringBuilder();
strBlder.Append("http://someurl//data");
//use the previously used variable splitindex
strBlder.Replace("//", "/", splitindex + 1, (http.Length) - splitindex);
```